# How can i show blue arrows before <li> while not using a media query to target IE 9 and higher?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I had the following problem: The blue arrows are missing in IE 11 (IE 9 and above). On Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox it works fine.

Using this code:

```
ul.list li::before {
    font-family: "Glyphicons Halflings";
    content: "";
    color: #1CAFED;
    display: table-cell;
    padding-right: 10px;
    font-size: 0.65em;
}

<ul class="list">
    <li>
        <a href="/werken-in/amsterdam">Amsterdam</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

As you can see, there are no blue arrows in IE:
[image]

In Chrome/Firefox it shows this:[image]

I solved this problem using this code:

```
@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
    .formatted ul li span {
        display: block;
        float: right;
        text-align: left;
        width: 96.23%;
    }

.formatted ul li::before {
display: inline-block;
    width: 3.77%;
  }
}

ul.list li::before {
font-family: "Glyphicons Halflings";
content: "";
    color: #1CAFED;
    display: table-cell;
    padding-right: 10px;
    font-size: 0.65em;
}

<ul>
    <li>
        <span>Amsterdam</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Notice the @media query. The "-ms-high-contrast" targets IE 9 and higher. I am looking for a more cleaner (one-way) solution that will work on both IE and Chrome, instead of using a media query just to target IE 9 and above. Can somebody help me? If anything is not clear, please let me know and I will try my best to explain.

Comment: Use `:before` instead of `::before`, IE has poor support for `::` CSS3 pseudo-element selectors.

Comment: @Terry Tried that, but does not make a difference unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself:

Use this code:

```
ul.list li::before {
    font-family: "Glyphicons Halflings";
    content: "";
    color: #1CAFED;
    padding-right: 10px;
    font-size: 1rem;
    display: inline; <-------- instead of display: table-cell;
    padding-top: 3px;
}
```